# Vim syntax/compile-time error highlighting

Tags: syntax-highlighting, vim

Is there a Vim script that periodically tries to compile/interpret the code that I'm working on, and highlights syntax errors? I'd like it to point out that something is wrong between these lines:

```
int a = 42
cout << a << endl;
```

Such a thing would save me loads of time. I'm primarily searching for a Perl-syntax checker, but I'd also be interested in similar plugins for other languages.

**Update**: Another error I'd like it to point out:

```
int a == 42;
cout << a << endl;
```

Comment: You might want to just get to where `:make` does what you want, and map a key to it, so that instead of "periodically", you have "whenever I push <F2>" or some such. Errors in a preview window aren't exactly the same as highlighting, but it's built-in functionality. (For Perl, you should just need to set `makeprg` to `perl -c`.)

Comment: I used ActiveState's Komodo for a while. Hugely impressed with its pointing-out-syntax-errors-while-editing. Thing is, wasn't such a great productivity boost. The debugger was neat (particularly when stepping through a cgi script on a server far, far away).

Comment: I'd hacked a solution by myself :) you can refer to [Get AsyncCommand work with errormarker][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/q/7963021/108565

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [eclim](http://eclim.org/) : once your eclim server is set up and running, you can use the Vim command [:Validate](http://eclim.org/vim/c/validate.html) to run a code validation on your file.

Basically, it uses the validation available in eclipse and display it in Vim/gVIm in the location list. (use `:lopen` )

For your example, the location list contains :

```
test.cpp|1 col 11 error| Syntax error
test.cpp|2 col 1 error| Syntax error
```

(the col 11 corresponds to location of the missing `;`)

By default the validation is run every time you save a buffer.

The error description are not really crystal clear but once you find the line with the error, you usually spot the error pretty easily.

Answer (score 1):

Auto-indenting should do it. When you start your new line with an extra indentation level it probably means that either you entered a new block or that you did not finish a statement.

Comment: That would solve my example, but there are all kinds of errors that a compiler finds, e.g. the one I just updated by answer with.