# Get AsyncCommand work with errormarker?

Tags: vim

I found [AsyncCommand](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3431) on [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/666453/running-make-from-gvim-in-background), and found it is a terrific tool! I am trying to get it work with [errormarker plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1861), but encountered some problem.

i don't know exactly what the problem is. I traced errormarker's script, and found error use following script to hook `QuickFixCmdPost` to event, and set markers to lines of source files.

```
augroup errormarker
    autocmd QuickFixCmdPost make call <SID>SetErrorMarkers()
augroup END
```

According to the `:help`, the second argument(`make`) is the `pattern` of the file(for example: `*.html`). I don't what is a `make` file pattern, I tried

```
autocmd QuickFixCmdPost AsyncMake call <SID>SetErrorMarkers()
```

It does not work(sure). But I don't know what else I can do. I do googled "AsyncCommand errormarker" but get nothing.

Is there are any comment? Any suggestion is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution.

The solution works, but ugly.

The key is to call `errormarker`'s `SetErrorMarkers()` function at the right time automatically.

I tried Peter Rincker's solution, but it turns out the `AsyncCommandQuickFixCmdPost` fired too early. The quickfix list is not set yet. So `SetErrorMarkers()` does nothing.

I read some `AsyncCommand`'s manual and traced some code, the `AsyncMake` is actually a wrapper, which invoke

```
asynccommand#run(cmd, handler)
```

with

```
asynccommand#run("make", asynchandler#qf)
// where asynchandler#qf is the handler to read quick fix list back.
```

So, since `asynchandler#qf` can be called at the right time, I traced the call point of the `asynchandler#qf`, and find the function `asynccommand#done` in file `asynccommand.vim` line 92 call the `asynchandler#qf`.

```
function! asynccommand#done(temp_file_name)
  " Called on completion of the task
  let r = s:receivers[a:temp_file_name] "handlers are registered in s:receivers
  if type(r.dict) == type({})
    call call(r.func, [a:temp_file_name], r.dict)
  else
    call call(r.func, [a:temp_file_name])
  endif
  unlet s:receivers[a:temp_file_name]
  delete a:temp_file_name
endfunction
```

Got you!

Let's add some code at line 101 to invoke the `SetErrorMarkers()` function

```
  ...
  unlet s:receivers[a:temp_file_name]
  if exists("*ExposeSetErrorMarkers")
    call ExposeSetErrorMarkers()
  endif
  delete a:temp_file_name
  ...
```

Notice the function we called here is `ExposeSetErrorMarkers()` not `SetErrorMarkers()`. Because the `SetErrorMarkers()` is a script local function, can not be called from outside of the script. so I add a delegate function `ExposeSetErrorMarkers()` in `errormarker.vim` to expose that function.

```
function! ExposeSetErrorMarkers()
    call s:SetErrorMarkers()
endfunction
```

Moreover, I add some auto commands to my `.vimrc`

```
au BufWritePost *cpp AsyncMake
au BufWritePost *cc  AsyncMake
au BufWritePost *h   AsyncMake
```

to invoke AsyncMake automatically every time I save my source file.

It works! Ugly, though :P

Answer (score 3):

AsyncCommand uses `cgetfile` under the covers to fill in the quickfix window. It seems that `cgetfile` does not trigger a `QuickFixCmdPost` event. In order to get `SetErrorMarkers()` to fire at the correct moment (or at all). We need to either create a new event or couple the errormarker plugin into the AsyncCommand. Since we are all good and non-lazy programmers around here, I am going to suggest the evented approach as it offers more a bit more flexibility.

Since you are already editing a plugin, I hope you do not not mind making a small addition to the AsyncCommand plugin. I am assuming you have the latest version from [github](https://github.com/pydave/AsyncCommand/).

We are going to create a new user event that AsyncCommand will trigger after `cgetfile`. In file: `autoload/asynchandler.vim` after line 63 insert the following line.

```
doautocmd User AsyncCommandQuickFixCmdPost
```

Should look something like this:

```
exe 'botright ' . self.mode . "open"
let cmd = self.command . ' ' . a:temp_file_name
exe cmd
doautocmd User AsyncCommandQuickFixCmdPost
if type(self.title) == type("") && self.title != ""
```

Now you can edit error the error marker plugin to look like this:

```
augroup errormarker
    autocmd QuickFixCmdPost make call <SID>SetErrorMarkers()
    autocmd User AsyncCommandQuickFixCmdPost call <SID>SetErrorMarkers()
augroup END
```

Comment: Thank you for answering! I tried you solution, and found the AsyncCommand is more complicated then we thought: when the `User AsyncCommandQuickFixCmdPost` is triggered, the async-eventhandler is actually not complete, so the quickfix in the main(server) program is not set yet, so the `SetErrorMarkers()` will set nothing. I had found other solution, it works, but not elegant as yours, I will post it :)